# How to use an abstract factory with realizations of an interface that have different constructor parameters?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, abstract-factory

Everything works fine till the constructors of the realizations are the same. However, I have a sort of dilemma when the constructors are different. Is it okay or maybe there is an architecture issue? Here is the code:

```cs
public class CategoryViewFactory : ICategoryViewFactory
{
    private readonly ActiveProgressions _activeProgressions;

    public CategoryViewFactory(ActiveProgressions activeProgressions)
    {
        _activeProgressions = activeProgressions;
    }

    public ICategoryView? Create(CategoryType type, Category category)
    {
        return type switch
        {
            CategoryType.Category => new CategoryView(category),
            CategoryType.Subcategory => new SubcategoryView(category, _activeProgressions),
            _ => null
        };
    }
}
```

`ActiveProgression` is a singleton service which I inject using the container. Is it okay? And what I should do if, for instance, `ActiveProgression` is a transient service? How can I create `SubcategoryView` in this case?

The idea of putting extra parameters in `Create()` seems quite bad, but it also seems the only solution in this case.

Comment: If `ActiveProgressions` is a transient service, a possible solution is firstly to invent an `IActiveProgressions` interface for it, and secondly to pass to the `CategoryViewFactory` constructor another factory for creating `IActiveProgressions`. This would require modifying `SubcategoryView` to use an `IActiveProgressions` rather than an ``ActiveProgressions`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CategoryViewFactory`'s `Create` method acts as a Composer. A Composer is part of your application's [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/) that is responsible for composing instances. In this case the `Create` method is using [Pure DI](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/) rather can moving that responsibility to a DI Container.

As long as `CategoryViewFactory` is defined in the application's startup path, a.k.a. the Composition Root, everything what you're doing is perfectly fine. It's even fine for `ActiveProgression` to call back into the DI Container, *as long as `ActiveProgression` is part of the Composition Root as well. When `ActiveProgression` is defined *outside* the context of the Composition Root, it's use of the DI Container can be considered a Service Locator, which is [a well-known anti-pattern](https://freecontent.manning.com/the-service-locator-anti-pattern/).

> And what I should do if, for instance, ActiveProgression is a transient service?

As long as `CategoryViewFactory` is transient as well, there will be no problem. When `CategoryViewFactory` is singleton, however, `ActiveProgression` will become a [Captive Dependency](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/).

Although, what you're doing is perfectly fine, it might be less obvious for `CategoryViewFactory` to use Pure DI, while other parts of your Composition root use a DI Container. You can consider `CategoryViewFactory` to forward the responsibility of composition to the DI Container. For instance:

```cs
public class CategoryViewFactory : ICategoryViewFactory
{
    private readonly MyDiContainer container;

    public CategoryViewFactory(MyDiContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public ICategoryView? Create(CategoryType type, Category category)
    {
        var view = this.CreateInternal(type);
        view?.Initialize(category);
        return view;
    }

    private ICategoryView? CreateInternal(CategoryType type)
    {
        return type switch
        {
            CategoryType.Category => container.GetService<CategoryView>(),
            CategoryType.Subcategory => container.GetService<SubcategoryView>(),
            _ => null
        };
    }
}
```

Notice how in this case, the `Category` runtime data is not supplied any longer to the constructor of the created views. This simplifies the creation of those objects, because their construction no longer depends on the existence of runtime data, which is [a good practice](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/runtime-data/). This also requires changing your `ICategoryView`.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed and great answer! It really explains a lot for me. The idea to get out of the runtime data in the constructors and using a DI container instead of Pure DI makes everything really easier. Thank you for such valuable articles to read, I am very delighted

Comment: By they way, what should I do if my realizations require different sets of runtime data? For example, ```SubcategoryView``` requires ```(int id, string name, bool something)``` whereas ```CategoryView``` requires only ```(string name)```. What should I do in this case? I've thought about a kind of structure to inject all of these data but it must be unobvious which data you should provide with the structure to the specific realization. Is it a design smell?

Comment: That really depends on your architecture or design you are using. With MVC a view and its controller are coupled through the model (the data) that the controller supplies to the view. With MVVM the view understands the contract of the view model class which contains data and functions for the view to call. So how to proceed really depends on many factors. But here's an idea: consider making the `ICategoryView` generic, as in `ICategoryView<TData>`, with an `Init(TData)` method, where `TData` can be a class that contains the required info, such as `(int id, string name, bool something)`.